# Why FPS Limiter is failing in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, frame-rate

I have a game public source, And the FPS Limiter is failing in Windows 10.
If I change the g_nFrameLimitValue to 333 for example, this limits for 280, and If I try to limit to 250, I get 209. I have these issues only in Windows 10. (Windows 8 Im not sure, 7 working fine).

Code below:

```
void OnUpdate()
{
    {
        g_nFrameCount++;
        DWORD currentTime=timeGetTime();

        { // 1ÃÊ´ç ÇÁ·¹ÀÓ Á¦ÇÑ (Á¦ÇÑ Á¾·ù: ¹«Á¦ÇÑ, 60fps, 120fps, 240fps)
            float fFrameLimit = 0;
            if(g_nFrameLimitValue > 0)
                fFrameLimit = 1000/g_nFrameLimitValue;
            if( (currentTime-g_dwLastTime) < fFrameLimit )
            {
                Sleep( (int)fFrameLimit - (currentTime-g_dwLastTime) );
                currentTime=timeGetTime();
            }
            g_dwLastTime = currentTime;
        }

        if(g_dwLastFPSTime+FPS_INTERVAL<currentTime)
        {
            g_fFPS=(g_nFrameCount-g_nLastFrameCount)*FPS_INTERVAL/((float)(currentTime-g_dwLastFPSTime)*(FPS_INTERVAL/1000));
            g_dwLastFPSTime=currentTime;
            g_nLastFrameCount=g_nFrameCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are limited to full multiplies of 70 Hz.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand. Thank you